# Have Q(s) ever contacted humanity outside of linear time?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

Q always seems to appear in chronological order. His first encounter with Picard is Picard's first encounter with Q... and so on. Captains that come later know about Q from Picard's briefings.

Obviously Q(s) can travel through time and manipulate the space-time continuum. But they seem mysteriously bound to the same timeline as humanity.

The speed of time is clearly adjustable. When Q has a kid, he grows up faster than normal. But does grow up... (he isn't older in year X and younger in year X+1)

**Are there any examples of non-chronological encounters by Q?**

Comment: The Q are (for all intents and purposes) omniscient. Until Q(uinn)'s suicide, they know where the course of their life leads and seek to ensure that all of their fellow Q follow that path ruthlessly.

Comment: “they seem mysteriously bound to the same timeline as humanity” — why bound? Maybe they're just respecting the human perception of time to facilitate communication. It's much easier to mess lower species if they roughly understand what on earth you're talking about. Having conversations without the basis of a linear timeline [just results in confusion for everyone](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Prophet).

Comment: @Valorum I thought that at first, but then why would Q put humanity on trial? if he knows what they'll turn into? just a game right?

Comment: "*At the beginning of the New Era, life as a Q was a continuous dialogue of discovery and issues and humour from all over the universe. But look at them now. Listen to their dialogue now.*" - You can't have discovery without the linear flow of time.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite probably the right answer. I'm just wondering if there any examples that disprove that

Comment: @LevenTrek - Picard was the one that put humanity on trial. Q was just riffing off of what he said.

Comment: Counter-argument (from the same episode) "*As difficult as it is for you to imagine, for me, immortality is impossible to endure any longer. In the Continuum, an individual has an obligation to be responsible to the path his life will follow.*" - You can't follow a path if you can't see the direction in which it leads.

Comment: I'm convinced that the Q(s) COULD encounter humanity non-chronologically. just wondering if they ever do (did/will)

Comment: edited the title to help. it's not as clever/clean but it's more on point

Answer (score 1):

I believe the TNG finale [All Good Things...](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Good_Things..._(episode)) qualifies.

Picard experiences shifts in time, and finds himself at Farpoint Station seven years ago (during the events of the pilot).

> PICARD: The last time that I stood here was seven years ago.
>
> Q: Seven years ago. How little do you mortals understand time. Must you be so linear, Jean-Luc?

Q then explains that Picard is responsible for an ongoing spatial anomaly that he claims will destroy humanity.

It is later revealed that

> The anomaly is indeed being caused by Picard... in the future! It is the result of three tachyon beams converging at the same point in space from three different points in time, from three different versions of the *Enterprise*:  one from seven years ago during an alternative timeline contemporaneous with the series pilot, one from the "present" during the series finale, and one from an alternative future in which Picard is retired from Starfleet. The anomaly grows "backwards" in time, wiping out life on Earth billions of years "before" it forms.

Sorting out the order of events is made difficult by the fact the entire episode is a massive causality paradox. But when Q appears to present-day Picard, he knows the reason behind the anomaly--meaning that he must know about

> the third, alternative future timeline

Since the anomaly would not exist without it. Therefore, when Q appears in this episode, he has already experienced the future, and thus his appearance is non-chronological from Picards' perspective.

Comment: Disagree that All Good Things is an answer.  The question is regarding the fact it seems Q's appearances are in the same order for Q, the Enterprise crew, and the viewers.  Now if you could prove Q went from Encounter at Farpoint to Lower Decks that would be a non chronological example.

Comment: @lucasbachmann But All Good Things proves that they _aren't_ in the same order. Q in AGT has observed things that, for the _Enterprise_ crew and the viewers, haven't happened yet, hence his sequencing of events is different, if it even has a well-defined sequence. Unless you count the entire episode as one "appearance", which seems like an arbitrary restriction.

Comment: No one disputes Q can time travel.  But again the question was if and why Q's appearances are in the same chronological order as everyone else's.   For All Good Things Q's appearances are in the correct order for Picard's conciousness and the viewer.   So it fails as a counter example.  Additionally you'd have a hard time proving how real those other timelines were (though I suspect to a Q it is a trivial difference)  versus just being a Q created virtual scenario there's plenty of examples of. Examples like Sherwood forest or post World war 3 courtrooms.